# Remove all Indentation

Tags: c#, xml, indentation

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<DataRow>
    <Name><![CDATA[DateAdd]]></Name>
    <Description><![CDATA[Adds or subtracts some interval of time from a date or time.]]></Description>
    <Syntax><![CDATA[DateAdd(interval, number, date)]]></Syntax>
    <Notes><![CDATA[Interval may be:
        yyyy=year
        q=quarter
        m=month
        y=day of year
        d=day
        w=weekday
        ww=week of year
        h=hour
        n=minute
        s=second]]>
    </Notes>
</DataRow>
```

I want to remove all indentation even inside the `CDATA`. It is easy to add indentation using `XmlTextWriter` but I cannot find anything to remove indents.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Doesn't the `XmlWriterSettings` work then? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh and just to be clear, the XML you have is stored as XML? i.e. if its a plain string you might need to parse it first.

Comment: Lasse, I am sending the XML to translators and all are having problems with these tabs. Slowing the translation process. So that is why I want to get rid of them creating new XML without indentation.

Comment: cjb110, XmlWriterSettings with Formatting = Formatting.None; doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to remove all indentation, you don't need an XML parser/writer.

You can load the text as separate lines using File.ReadAllLines, and then process each one of them with string.TrimStart. Then save them back to disk using File.WriteAllLines.

*N.B.: File.WriteAllLines appends a newline at the end of the file (since it follows each line by a newline); if you don't want one, you should join the lines yourself.*

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous posters. An example of that would be the following

```
string path = "path_to_file";
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines.Select(line => line.TrimStart()));
```

This will remove all the leading white spaces from all the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to forget that it's XML. Read the file in, split it into lines, trim the whitespace off each line and write the file back out again. The `File.ReadLines` and `String.TrimStart` methods are likely to be useful for that.

This avoids any issues with XML parsers preserving layout (although you can save an `XDocument` telling it to disable formatting), but also would remove the indentation from the CDATA section, which an XML parser won't touch because CDATA is explicitly defined as being just a string, which the XML parser cannot interpret in any way.

So it seems like a slightly odd requirement, not really in keeping with how XML is usually handled, and therefore I'd suggest not treating it like XML.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this may help:

```
string markup =
@"<Root>
    <Child>
        <GrandChild/>
    </Child>
</Root>";

XmlReader nodeReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(markup));
nodeReader.MoveToContent();

XElement xRoot = XElement.Load(nodeReader);
var result = xRoot.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

result will contain unindented string.